# Embedded versions of java 6?

Tags: java

I just inherited an application that will only run on Java 6. Currently it installs with its own embedded java: jre1.6.0_01, however I need to update that embedded jre to the latest version java 6.

I can find embedded version of java on Oracle's website below, but only for 7 and 8. Does anyone know where I can find an embedded version of java 6.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/java-embedded-java-se-download-359230.html#javase7update

This is a stop gap as the entire application is going to be given a rewrite soon, so please don't suggest java 7.

Comment: I know the feeling, I'm constrained to use Java 6 as well and I feel sorry for you...

Comment: We just had a presentation on the benefits of Java 8. I am super motivated to move away from Java 6 too.

Comment: I've been using Java 8 for a little while at home now, and it is definitely full of interesting stuff. I'm really disappointed that the company does not want to change their JRE, at least to version 7.

Comment: We're working on it  but we have to find a few solutions for our legacy apps first.

Comment: I was talking about my own company, sorry for the ambiguity ^^ But I hope you'll be able to get there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this link for the version 6 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/java-se-embedded-archive-1862184.html ?

This seems to be the [latest](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/default-1934076.html)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you I couldn't find them with Google!

Answer (score 1):

These [archived builds](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/java-se-embedded-archive-1862184.html) might be of use.

Comment: Thank you. I swear  I did like 20 google searches trying to find these silly things!